# Move the Navigation bar above the header

Tags: css

I have tried a few CSS customizations to no avail, such as below

```
.topnavbar.navbar-fixed-top {
  z-index: 1030 !important;
}
```

The website is http://fastlanehelp.org.

Comment: honestly, I can not get what are you trying to solve, could you please add some more detail to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your navbar to end exactly where your first section starts, you have to add to that section `margin-top: /* navbar height in pixels */;`